# uploading and saving base64 image data to a Django image field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, base64

I'm having trouble saving base64 image data to a django image field, this is what i have tried:

so basically i receive the base64 image data from the front end, using axios POST request. then handle the image data in my django rest framework api View.

I have tried two variations:

1) writing the decoded base64 to a TemporaryFile, then passing it to the `imageField`.

2) opening the `TemporaryFile` using `PIL.Image.open(img_temp)` and then converting the `PIL.Image` to a `InMemoryUploadedFile` and passing that to the `imageField`.

However in both cases i get an error: `image
:
["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]`

I'm not quite sure why i get this error because when i used the `img.show()`, the image came out fine.

**Django rest framework**

```
        base64_data = request.data['image_data'][22:]
        decode_image = base64.b64decode(base64_data)
        img_temp = TemporaryFile()
        img_temp.write(decode_image)
        img_temp.flush()

        img = PIL.Image.open(img_temp)
        img_format = '.' + img.format
        img.show()

        image_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(image_io, format=img.format)
        file = InMemoryUploadedFile (
            image_io,
            None,
            'photo' + img_format,
            'image/' + img.format,
            sys.getsizeof(image_io),
            None,
        )
        img.close()

        data = {
            'image': File(img_temp) # I have tried passing File(img_tem) and "file" into the image field
        }

        serializer = ListSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: figured it out

```
        base64_data = request.data['image_data'][22:]
        decode_image = base64.b64decode(base64_data)

        img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(decode_image))
        img_format = '.' + img.format
        img.show()

        fileData = BytesIO(decode_image)
        file = InMemoryUploadedFile ( # arguments: 'file', 'field_name', 'name', 'content_type', 'size', and 'charset'
            fileData,
            None,
            'photo' + img_format,
            'image',
            len(decode_image),
            None,
        )
        img.close()

        data = {
            'image': file
        }

        serializer = ListSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            instance.save()
```